# Cytoscape.js large data performance vs sigma.js

Tags: javascript, performance, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm having a lot of trouble rendering a graph in cytoscape.js with ~1,000 nodes and ~5,000 edges (takes a very long time to render, once rendered impossible to interact with since browser is overloaded), however the same size graph appears to render fine and works well with sigma.js (http://sigmajs.org/).

I'm wondering why there is such a vast performance difference in the two libraries. I'd like to use cytoscape.js if possible since it seems much better documented and easier to work with, but I can only do so if it is able to work with sizable graphs in the browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigma has hacks that allow it to render faster, such as disabling edge rendering on viewport events.  If you `make all` from the trunk, the `hideEdgesOnViewport` init option should do what you're looking for -- giving you more or less the same level of performance as sigma.